# How to compare zip files' contents?

Tags: bash, console, zip, krusader

Is there any tool to compare zips by content?

maybe some krusader addon or command-line magic?

Answer (score 4):

```
    Package: zipcmp
    ...
    Description-en: compare contents of zip archives
     zipcmp compares two zip archives and checks if they contain the same files,
     comparing their names, uncompressed sizes, and CRCs. File order and compressed
     size differences are ignored.
```